# Can you safely tame an Eastern Yellowjacket?

Tags: wasps

I know this is a weird and sort of crazy question, but can you safely tame wasps as pets? Here's what I'm thinking: I have non-filtered all-natural 100% honey. I know that adult wasps eat very sweet foods, so I'm wondering if I could use that to attract them and gain their trust? I'm pretty sure that I'll be dealing with Eastern Yellowjackets, but I think it might be a different species (its legs hang down, it has a long abdomen). Anyway, is there a specific way to do this or am I just supposed to slowly approach it with some honey on my finger and let it come to me when it smells it? Thanks in advance!
P.S. I'm new to this community so forgive me if this isn't such a great question.

Comment: Consider using something other than honey (like sugar water). Feeding honey to various social insects is a vector for insect diseases.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not sure about taming an individual, or even how you'd tell your pet one from another, but wasps really aren't that aggressive if you move slowly.

I've had them (European ones) crawling over my hand without issues before. I didn't have much choice - I was holding a beer in each hand, in a queue with nowhere to put them down, and the wasps came to lick the spilt beer off my hand. When I stated holding them closer to my face for a better look, and encouraging my daughter to look at their tiny tongues, people started to back away.

Answer (score 4):

This is an answer from a non-expert, and is based on my experience alone.  Location: Northern Virginia.

First, where are the yellow-jackets/wasps nesting?  If they are nesting in the ground, based on personal experience over quite a few years, I would sooner try to tame an adult tiger.

If they have a nest hanging aboveground, say under the eaves of your house, they are a variety or sub-species (species??) that is more laid back.  I used to share my outdoor breakfasts with them in the fall.  A little bit of egg, some jam, on a separate plate, they were polite and it was very companionable.

I hope someone will give you a more technical answer.

**PS** If you are in a mood for adult tigers, two things to consider:  (1) Are you allergic?  People can get very, very bad reactions.  (2) Do you have a short escape route planned out?  They will chase you.

Comment: I think the chase thing is a bit of a myth - they will follow the attack scent trail if there are enough stinging, but most of it is people running away and trapping insects in the wash of air behind them. Similar to how a biker can ride very close behind a truck and be pulled along by the air.

Comment: Interesting point, but it sure felt like they were chasing me for 300 feet from the bottom of my driveway to my front door.   When they caught up to me,  they  stung.